# What does "deb8u3" in the version number of debian mean?

Tags: debian, version

The output of `uname -a` is:

`#1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u3 (2015-08-04)`

I failed to find any explanation for "u3" in the output so what does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that it's the third update of the 3.16.7-ckt11-1 version of the kernel for Debian 8. When Debian 8 was released, it had version 3.17.6-ckt11-1; when an update became necessary, a +deb8u1 suffix was added, then +deb8u2 on the following update, and +deb8u3 on the version you have.

You can see the details of the updates in the [changelog](https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/linux/blob/76724623a64402892e5da809728af207fb27e6eb/debian/changelog). This versioning scheme is documented in the last paragraph of [the section on NMUs and `debian/changelog` in Debian Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/pkgs.html#nmu-changelog), although it's not NMU-specific.

I'm pretty sure I've answered this here already, but I can't find the answer...